# Non Stop Kernel Panics on Mavericks

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

I've been facing a really hard kernel panic problem.
I bought this macbook pro 17" about 5 months ago and at that time I had a few kernel panics but didn't event bothered cause I could still use it anyway.

A month from now I couldn't even work cause there would be kp's every 5 minutes. I'm from Brazil and there's no Genius Bar over here so I sent to the authorized support guys in my city. It stayed there for about 2 weeks and they couldn't map the problem. I was told to try and send it to a different city via mail but i'm really afraid something would happen to the machine.

The thing is I have no more warranty and the support couldn't fix it. The only way to get pass the problem is to log in safe boot, which is what i'm doing now so that I can write.

The log is below and I'm not really sure but apparently they're different every time. I still believe it can be something I can solve at home due to the fact that in safe boot it works properly for as long as I want so I don't think it's hardware related, hopefully.

Anonymous UUID:       9A6F53D3-652E-95EA-C030-8CF98C4E04A5

```
Tue Jun 24 14:19:29 2014
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c09
family: 6 model: 42 stepping: 7 microcode: 40
signature: 0x206a7
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2860QM CPU @ 2.50GHz
9 error-reporting banks
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xfe00000000800400
IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003fff8fdcb166
IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x0000000000000001
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000004
IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xfe00000000800400
IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x00003fff8fdcb166
IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x0000000000000001
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8026adc7e9): "Machine Check at 0x00007fff8d955225, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000011550d000, CR3: 0x0000000066962081, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x00007fe5cc0a5e00, RCX: 0x000000000cc0a5df, RDX: 0x0000000000801420\n" "RSP: 0x00007fff5ef7fae0, RBP: 0x00007fff5ef7fae0, RSI: 0x0000000000000006, RDI: 0x00007fe5cc0a5e00\n" "R8:  0x00007fe5cc0a5e00, R9:  0x00007fe5cc058fe0, R10: 0x00007fe5cc000000, R11: 0x00007fff90126e24\n" "R12: 0x000007fe5cc0a5e0, R13: 0x0000000100c82000, R14: 0x0000000102c9ba00, R15: 0x0000000000000006\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000a02, RIP: 0x00007fff8d955225, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.100.13/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c :168
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff813291bdd0 : 0xffffff8026a22fa9
0xffffff813291be50 : 0xffffff8026adc7e9
0xffffff813291bfb0 : 0xffffff8026af3cff
```

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.WebKit

Mac OS version:
13D65

```
Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: ADD73AE6-88B0-32FB-A8BB-4F7C8BE4092E
Kernel slide:     0x0000000026800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8026a00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,3 (Mac-942459F5819B171B)




System uptime in nanoseconds: 193949226054
last loaded kext at 14558884752: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60 (addr 0xffffff7fa8528000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 2.6.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver 1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.14.15
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer 1.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.5.13
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.5.26
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.6.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.6.1f2
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000 1.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics 8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.1.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 2.0.4d1
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller 1.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB 8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.5.26
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor 3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter 104
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 325.7
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient 3.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 666.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI 656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.security.quarantine 3
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 153
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 217.92.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.1f2
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.20
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.6
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport 1.2.2
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.5.26
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.5.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite 656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 3.2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 630.35
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 677.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 7
com.apple.security.sandbox 278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 23
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread 1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Appreciate if anyone can help.
Thanks for now!

Comment: The easiest way is probably to backup using timemachine or manually and then reinstalling (via recovery partition or a usb drive) and restoring your personal files (or user), reinstall applications from scratch if possible. If it still happens, try using a different user (or even reinstalling without restoring the backup at first - if it still happens than it's a hardware issue, there are things like TechTool to check (some) hardware yourself, otherwise an Apple Repair Center should do a hardware check on it)

Comment: You mentioned it's a 17".  Is it by any chance an early 2011 MacBook Pro?  That model has known issues with the discrete graphics chip burning up.  That could easily cause a kernel panic.  The faulting thread being WebKit makes sense.  That's Safari right there.  If you go to a web page that requests video acceleration, your kernel would try to switch to the discrete graphics chip, and BAM! Kernel panic.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that your Web kit is the creator or the problems.

That is why the service guys could not reproduce the problem (different Network set up).

Try operating for a while without been connected to the Web.

Here are some trouble shooting steps I would recommend:

In Safe mode the AMD graphics card is Disabled (so are also all 3d party applications). I have a problem her: Your model should have the AMD Radeon HD 6750M!. 
But the driver loaded is the com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000 1.2.2

- To disable the AMD graphics (temporarly to prvoe it is it doing ot):

  Boot into Single-User mode
  Execute the following commands:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy /
    /sbin/mount -uw /
    mkdir /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
    cd /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
    mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* .
    mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* .
    touch /System/Library/Extensions
    exit
```

- Under Apple About This mac, look up what you actually have as Graphics chip.

Hardware:

First check I/O errors (disk or memory) by opening console (in your utility folder) and typing I/O in the filter window.

That model of yours will have the Apple Hardware Test installed, use it to do more hardware test.

Software:

- Try different user to see if problem persist
- If no problem with that user, repair your User account. Reset ACL's.
- Use Console after system crash/lockup, remember the time, and find in Console the activity before the crash.
- update your [EFI and SMC to latest](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1237).
- Last not Least,- If you have saved the Mavericks installer use it to reinstall, if not use the Internet recovery.

Most important is to get the information from Console at the time stamp of the crash to see what lead to it.

Your system information of relevance:

Mavericks 10.9.3 (Mac OS version: 13D65)

Graphics AMD Radeon HD 6750M

Answer (score 1):

There are several Apple support pages on Kernel Panics.

"When your computer spontaneously restarts or displays "Your computer restarted because of a problem."' -- http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4636

"Mac OS X: How to log a kernel panic" -- http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2546

See the links on these pages if you want to go deeper.